# Get-ADGroupMember from list

Tags: powershell, get, active-directory

Attempting to run 1 ps script by having the groups in a text file..

```
    $groups = Get-Content c:\groups.txt {
    foreach($Group in $Groups) 

    Get-ADGroupMember -identity "$groups" | select samaccountname,name "c:\test.txt" }
```

> Missing statement body in foreach loop. At line:3 char:1
>   +  <<<< Get-ADGroupMember -identity "$groups" | select samaccountname,name >> "c:\test.txt" }
>       + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingForeachStatement

Answer (score 1):

You will need to split your input file up with the newline character. You can pipe all groups into a single 'Select' to output too:

```
(Get-Content c:\groups.txt) -split '\n' | % {
    Get-ADGroupMember -identity $_
} | select samaccountname,name | Out-File "c:\test.txt"
```

**Edit:**
This will use a calculated property so you can capture the group name:

```
(Get-Content c:\groups.txt) -split '\n' | % {
    Get-ADGroupMember -identity $_ | select @{n="Group";e={$_}},samaccountname,name
} | Out-File "c:\test.txt"
```

If you end up converting the output to a spreadsheet, you may consider `ConvertTo-Csv` also.

Comment: There was a typo - I somehow used '℅' instead of '%'

Comment: Yeah, That's perfect. 
 I am trying to group the results per group in the text file.

E.g: So the Samaccountname and name is grouped per group ... if that makes sense?

Comment: Do you know how to 'group' the output by the AD groups?

Comment: You could pipe to `Group-Object -Property group` - I'm not sure if this will translate well to output to a text file though.

Comment: Ignore above comment : Do you know how to display the 'group' name within the output? So I can identify which samaccountname and name is part of which group.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, I've modified this to remove all the obvious errors.

```
Get-Content c:\groups.txt -OutVariable groups | foreach {
    Get-ADGroupMember -identity $_ | select samaccountname,name | 
        out-file c:\test.txt -Append }
```

Comment: That does work, however do I need to have it a special way in the groups.txt file? It only works if there is 1 group in the txt file. If I have multiple groups (1 on each line) there is no output.

Comment: see the second answer ;)